# Are lambdas constructors for delegate types?

Tags: c#, lambda, constructor, rhino-mocks

I've discovered that Rhino Mocks' AssertWasCalled fails when I use lambdas as parameters to the method being asserted.

**TEST :**
`_mockDoer.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Print(y => Console.WriteLine("hi")));`

**CODE INSIDE SYSTEM UNDER TEST :**
`_doer.Print(y => Console.WriteLine("hi")));`

This has made me think of lambdas as, effectively, constructors for delegate types.

Am I missing anything important when I think of lambdas as constructors for delegate types?

Comment: Great question. But `AssertWasCalled` is so evil. Test behavior instead.   The *right* way to test things here is to test the behavior. But if you insist on using `AssertWasCalled`, you should be mocking a `TextWriter` and asserting that `WriteLine(string)` is called on the mock with the `string` parameter being `"hi"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, they're not really "constructors" in any of the normal uses of the word "constructor".

They're expressions which can be converted to delegate types or expression tree types - the latter being essential when it comes to out-of-process LINQ.

If you're really asking whether it's expected that using two "equivalent" lambda expressions can create unequal delegate instances: yes, it is. IIRC, the C# language specification even calls out that that's the case.

However, using the same lambda expression more than once won't *always* create different instances:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action[] actions = new Action[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            actions[i] = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(actions[0] == actions[1]);
    }
}
```

On my box, that actually prints `True` - `actions[0]` and `actions[1]` have the exact same value - they refer to the same instance. Indeed, we can go further:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object x = CreateAction();
        object y = CreateAction();
        Console.WriteLine(x == y);
    }

    static Action CreateAction()
    {
        return () => Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Again, this prints `True`. It's *not* guaranteed to, but here the compiler has actually created a static field to cache the delegate the first time it's required - because it doesn't capture any variables etc.

Basically this is a compiler implementation detail which you should *not* rely on.

Comment: +1. I didn't know this >> `two "equivalent" lambda expressions can create unequal delegate instances: yes, it is`.

Comment: It makes sense since the same lambda code can "pull in" different local variables with different types (but the same names).

Comment: Interesting, so your example outputs `true` but if you unroll the `for` loop then it gives `false`.  In otherwords don't depend on it one way or another.

Comment: @Davy8: At that point you've got two separate lambda expressions - I don't believe they're *currently* ever treated as "the same". I think Eric Lippert may even have a blog post about it somewhere.

Comment: @Nawaz: Another interesting point is that they will have the same hashcode :)

Comment: @leppie: Interesting, and crazy at the same time, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

Just to expand on Jon's (excellent, as always) answer: in current implementations of C#, if "the same" lambda appears in *two different source code locations* then the two lambdas are never realized into equal delegates. However, we reserve the right to in the future detect this situation and unify them.

Whether the converse holds or not is also implementation-dependent. If two delegates are created from a lambda at a particular source code position, the delegates might or might not have equality. There are some scenarios where it is impossible for the delegates to have equality (because they are closed over different instances of local variables, for example). In situations where it *is* possible for them to have equality, *most of the time they do*, but there are a few cases where we could perform this optimization and do not, just because the compiler is not yet sophisticated enough.

Comment: The first paragraph of your answer is (first of all: fascinating) directly relevant to what I'm seeing with Rhino Mocks. Two "same" lambdas in "two different source code locations" -- indeed, as my tests show, their equality never materializes.  This was a surprise.  I do hope that providing reliable equality for similarly idential lamdas proves possible in the future.

Comment: @lance: I'm not sure promising to provide such equality is practical.  Of course, you could write a function that caches the lambda it returns.

Comment: @Eric Lippert could you please give us your take on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524453/what-is-the-rationale-for-small-stack-even-when-memory-is-available