# What is the rationale for small stack even when memory is available?

Tags: operating-system

Recently, I was asked in an interview, why would you have a smaller stack when the available memory has no limit? Why would you have it in 1KB range even when you might have 4GB physical memory? Is this a standard design practice?

Comment: Yes, because having really, really deep recursion is an antipattern. :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smaller your stacks, the more of them you can have. A 1kB stack is pretty useless, as I can't think of an architecture that has pages that small. A more typical size is 128kB-1MB.

Since each thread has its own stack, the number of stacks you can have is an upper limit on the number of threads you can have. Some people complain about the fact that they can't create more than 2000 threads in a standard 2GB address space of a 32-bit Windows process, so it's not surprising that some people would want even smaller stacks to allow even more threads.

Also, consider that if a stack has to be completely reserved ahead of time, it is carving a chunk out of your address space that can't be returned until the stack isn't used anymore (i.e. the thread exits). That chunk of reserved address space then limits the size of a contiguous allocation you can make.

Comment: Thanks @Gabe, that explains it very well. I never thought in terms of threads or allocation ahead of time, without need for a it.

Comment: Confused on the last part... is using up 4 KiB of contiguous virtual address space really that different from 1 MiB of contiguous space, when you have so many gigabytes anyway?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Consider the situation where you create 1000 threads and then all exit but the last one. Assume a 2GB address space where stacks are allocated contiguously. If you had 1MB stacks, your address space is partitioned into two 1GB segments. If you had 4kB stacks, your address space is partitioned into a 4MB segment and a 1.996GB segment.

Comment: @Gabe: Oooh, you mean in the same process... sorry I was thinking of multiple processes, my bad.

Comment: Those "some people" who want 2000 threads in a process are doing something deeply, deeply wrong. Imagine having 2000 motorbikes but only four riders, and the riders stop their bike, run to the next one, drive it for a few metres, stop, run to the next one... Not an efficient way to solve a problem. When we have thousand-processor machines then it makes sense to have a couple thousand threads, but not before.

Comment: @Eric: I was trying not to be judgemental, but you're right that most people who want that many threads are probably doing somethiing wrong. Of course there are still perfectly legitimate reasons for having that many threads in a process, though.

Comment: @Gabe, unless you have at least a hundfred cores I can't see much point. the windows scheduling overhead if you don't have pending IO is *astonishingly* huge compared to cpu speed. 15ms is getting perilously close to actually being human perceptible, stack a few together and they are.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: My recently-booted Windows box has nearly 1000 threads even though my CPU can only schedule 4 simultaneously. Assuming that's fine for whatever reason, why can't that reason apply to a single process?

Comment: @Gabe, start going through them and count off all those: in a system provided thread pool designed to mitigate end process creation. Waiting on IO in some way, are the main thread in a process (process isolation still makes a lot of sense so as to justify the cost since the isolation domain in terms of security and safety merit the (significant) additional costs

Comment: @Gable, oh and anything managed will likely have a slightly higher number of threads as a 'fixed point' than normal ones that do next to nothing in normal usage, the finalizer thread, the JIT thread and potentially a GC thread (that can change quite a bit).

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: It seems like you and Eric are assuming that these thousands of threads are all CPU-bound. Simply assume that the threads are all mostly waiting on things or I/O bound.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: You're assuming that all the threads in a process were created by the same author, such that a single person can simply refactor his code and change how the system works (which is still not necessarily feasible because they may be using a language like Python where that's not easy). Stop making that assumption. Instead assume that there are dozens of different authors all writing services who don't know that they'll be running in the same process together.

Comment: @Gabe in that sort of situation then the coders of the components in question should aggressively minimise their usage of limited resources as a matter of good design. As such using system provided means to do this (system thread pool based timer call backs, async IO notifications and the like is even more important.

Comment: @Gabe, further more if you are doing something like that in Python (which is still trying to free itself from the GIL) then you're "doing it wrong" I'm afraid.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: You're missing the point. The only reason that threads are a limited resource in the first place is that they require a 1MB allocation for their stacks. If you allocate only 4k per stack, it's a nearly unlimited resource.

Comment: @Gabe they are indeed expensive in memory (more than just the 4K you suggest though, see the linked article in my answer) but it's more than that. Your scheduler still has to move them through their state transition model, your context switch handler has to stash away registers when they change, and being them back when they do (the von Neumann barrier isn't going away much as we wish it would) the stack they own, even at 4K is a hefty chunk of memory to page in (and the kernel bits that can't page cost you big time).

Comment: @Gabe permeative switching between *independent* tasks, often encapsulated at the process level, is entirely reasonable model. You cannot predict their interaction and they have to be isolated in address space anyway. within a process the same model works up to a certain point, at the moment roughly speaking to the number of logical cores present (it's not entirely clear if it will scale if we have 64+ cores' I suspect NUMA awareness would need to be baked into the app to make it work) but to seriously scale if you aren't embarrassingly parallel...

Comment: ...that you would work as separate processes (potentially on separate machine) you start to need to play ball with the OS/memory sub system since they start dominating at that stage. You can wish this isn't so, that you could just "list the things you want to do as simple, understandable threads" and that the system would get on with running everything efficiently, but that is not how it works (on any modern OS I know about). given the other mechanisms controlled by threads (stacks, locks, registers, priority, OS mechanisms to avoid starvation, fair share etc.) they will always be massively...

Comment: ...more expensive that structuring things yourself to maximise concurrency between dependencies via models that d not require you to create your own threads. I've rambled on about this too long so I'll leave it there.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are good; I just thought I'd point out an important misunderstanding inherent in the question. **How much physical memory you have is completely irrelevant**. Having more physical memory is just an optimization; it prevents having to use disk as storage. The precious resource consumed by a stack is *address space*, not *physical memory*. The bits of the stack that aren't being used right now are not even going to reside in physical memory; they'll be paged out to disk. But as soon as they are committed, they are consuming virtual address space.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the "real" answer, but my guess is:

- It's committed on-demand.
- Do you really need it?

If the system uses 1 MiB for a stack, then a typical system with 1024 threads would be using 1 GiB of memory for (mostly) nothing... which may not be what you want, especially since you don't really need it.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is, even though memory is huge these days, it is still *not* unlimited.  A 32-bit process is normally limited to 4GB of address space (yes, you can use PAE to increase that, but that requires support from the OS and a return to a segmented memory model.)  Each thread uses up some of that memory for its stack, and if a stack is megabytes in size -- whether it's paged  in or not -- it's taking up a significant part of the app's address space.

The smaller the stack, the more threads you can squeeze into the app, and the more memory you have available for everything else.  Ideally, you want a stack just large enough to handle all possible control flows through the thread, but small enough that you don't have wasted address space.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here. First, the limit on the stack size will put the limit on number of processes/threads in the system. And then too, the limit is not because of the size of physical memory but because of the limit on addressable virtual memory. Secondly, rarely processes/threads need more stack size then that, and if they do, they can ask for it (libraries handle this seamlessly). So, when starting a new process/thread, it makes sense to give them a small stack space.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers here already mention the core concept, that the most significant consumed resource of a stack is address space (since its implementation requires chunks of contiguous address space) and that the default space consumed on windows for each thread is not insignificant.

However the full story is extremely nuanced (and can and will change over time) over many layers and levels.

This article by Mark Russinovich as part of his "Pushing the limits of Windows" series goes into [extremely detailed levels of analysis](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx). The work is in no way an introductory article though, and most people would not consider it the sort of thing that would be expected to be known in a job interview unless perhaps you were interviewing for a job in that particular field.

Comment: Thanks for the articles link, looks like an interesting read.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because everytime you call a function the OS has to allocate memory to be the stack of that function. Because functions can chain, several function calls will incur more stack allocations. A large default stack size, like 4GiB, would be impractical. But that's just my guess...